# how I can change the color of the Bootstrap slider

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

please tell me how I can change the color of the Bootstrap slider. In my code, I made style changes, but they are not taking effect. The slider still has the classic white color.

```
{% extends 'dashboard_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #152A3D;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
    
    <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" style="background-color: #152A3D !important;">
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="background-color: #152A3D;">
            {% for manager, plot_html in plots.items %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" data-bs-interval="5000" style="background-color: #152A3D !important;">
                    {{ plot_html | safe }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the Bootstrap slider, you'll need to override those default styles.

Note that you need to target the specific elements related to the slider, and you may need to use more specific selectors or increase the specificity of your styles to override Bootstrap's default styles.

```
{% extends 'dashboard_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #152A3D;
        }

        /* Customize the background color of the carousel */
        #carouselExampleInterval {
            background-color: #152A3D !important;
        }

        /* Customize the background color of the carousel items */
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
            background-color: #152A3D !important;
        }

        /* Customize the color of the slider controls (optional) */
        .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
            background-color: #152A3D !important;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for manager, plot_html in plots.items %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" data-bs-interval="5000">
                    {{ plot_html | safe }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `!important` declaration is used to ensure that your styles take precedence over Bootstrap's default styles.

If the styles are still not taking effect, make sure your custom styles are correctly applied by inspecting the elements using your browser's developer tools.